# Listen event on 1st child in AngularJS directive using jqlite

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

I'm working on a side navigation, which has tree structure only one level deep.

Right now every thing is good, but instead of listening to events on the parent **li** I only want to listen on the 1st **a** tag.

```js
app.directive('subNav', function($animate, $compile) {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
   element.on('click', function(e){
    console.log(element);
    x = element;
    controller.toggleState();    
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    scope.$apply();
    /**x = element;
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(element.find('ul').hasClass('ng-hide')){
     $animate.removeClass(element.find('ul'), 'ng-hide');
     scope.$apply();
    } else {
     $animate.addClass(element.find('ul'), 'ng-hide');
     scope.$apply();
    }**/
   });
        },
        controller : [function(){
   var vm = this;
   vm.toggleState = function() {
    if(vm.state === "false"){
     vm.state = false;
    }
    vm.state = !vm.state;
   };
  }],
  controllerAs : "subNav",
  scope: {
   state: '@subNav'
  },
  bindToController: true
    };
});
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
     <li class="navigation-items active" sub-nav="false" >
      <a data="main-link"><i class="material-icons">perm_identity</i> Option 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav animate-hide" ng-hide="!subNav.state">
       <li><a><i class="material-icons bullet">fiber_manual_record</i> Item 1</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

[image]

**What happens here is when I click on *Option 1* the tree expands and closes but the big problem is even if I click on *item 1* the tree closes as I'm listening to events on the entire element.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution as soon as I posted the question. Solved this by using.

`angular.element(element).find('a').first().on('click', function(e){.....})`

instead of

`element.on('click', function(e){.....})`

If any one posts a better solution, I'll accept that answer.